# How do i use annotate to group the child models by the parent models?

Tags: python, django, django-annotate

I have 3 models. PeerReview Answer and Statement. A Peer review has many answers, Each answer belongs to a Statement (or question if you will)

What I want is to get all answers from all PeerReviews grouped by their statements. So the end result should be a dictionary where there key is a statement object, and the value is a list of all the answers for that particular statement. If you would print it out it would look something like this:

`{Statement A : [answer, answer, answer], Statement B : [answer,answer,answer], Statement C : etc etc}`

I know that for group by queries i should use the `annotate()` method but all the examples i find are about count and sum actions. How do i use annotate to get the above mentioned dictionary as a result?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want, you need to use the reverse foreign key relationship.

```
statements = Statement.objects.prefetch_related('answer_set__peer_review')
```

If you need a dictionary, then this would do it:

```
mapping = {s: list(s.answer_set.all()) for s in statements}
```

Comment: would this also group all the answers by their linked statement?

Comment: Yes because this is fetching all of the statements, then you access that statement's answers.